# c++ char* converted from a string using strdup doesn't equal original raw string

Tags: c, equality, cstring, strdup

What I'm wondering is why converting a string to a char* seems to make the new char* not equal to the literal string it came from.

If I have:

```
//raw versions of the string:
string s = "fun";
char* c = "fun";

char* s_convert = strdup(s.c_str()); //converting the string to char*

printf("(string) == 'fun' -> %d\n", (s == "fun"));
printf("(char*) == 'fun' -> %d\n", (c == "fun"));
printf("(char* convert) == 'fun' -> %d\n", (s_convert == "fun"));

printf("(string) == (char*) -> %d\n", (s == c)); //does new char* equal original string
```

produces:

```
(string) == 'fun' -> 1 //true
(char*) == 'fun' -> 1  //true
(char* convert) == 'fun' -> 0 //false
(string) == (char* convert) -> 1 //true
```

So the converted char* still equals the original string it came from. But for some reason `char* s_convert` doesn't equal the literal string that it came from, although the original `string s` does.

Why does this happen? And is there a better way I can convert a string to char* that won't cause this?

Comment: char * == "string" doesnt do what you think it does. It tests to see if the address of the char* == the address of the constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through your comparisons one by one:

```
printf("(string) == 'fun' -> %d\n", (s == "fun"));
```

Compares a `std::string` variable with a string literal. Works as expected (i.e. really checks whether `s` contains the string "fun"), because `std::string` has an overloaded `operator==` for that purpose.

```
printf("(char*) == 'fun' -> %d\n", (c == "fun"));
```

Compares the address stored in `c` with the address of the string literal "fun". The result can be true or false. In your case, it is true, because the compiler optimized your code: It saw you use "fun" multiple times, and only stores the string literal *once* in memory, so the address will always be the same. If, e.g., `c` had been assigned the literal "fun" in a different translation unit, the result would be false.

```
printf("(char* convert) == 'fun' -> %d\n", (s_convert == "fun"));
```

Compares the address stored in `s_convert` to the address of the string literal "fun". As mentioned above, the string literal "fun" has a particular address chosen by your compiler. It will not compare equal to an explicitly copied string (it's irrelevant that it comes from the `std::string` variable). The `strdup` creates newly allocated memory, so the address will not compare equal to anything that existed in memory before.

```
printf("(string) == (char*) -> %d\n", (s == c)); //does new char* equal original string
```

Again, compares an `std::string` to a C-style string. This really compares the strings and checks whether `s` contains the null-terminated string stored at the address `c` thanks to the overloaded `operator==` of `std::string`, so the result is true.

To summarize: The effects that you observe have nothing or little to do with the conversions between `std::string` and null-terminated C-style strings. You just don't compare what you think you compare. Use `strcmp` if you want to compare null-terminated "raw" strings, or use `==` when you compare `std::string` to something else, and you will bet the results that you expect.

Answer (score 5):

For pointers, `==` compares pointer values; it has no way to know that the pointer is supposed to point to a C-style string (rather than a single character, or an unterminated array), and doesn't look at whatever it points to. The pointer returned by `strdup` will not be the address of any string literal, since the purpose of the function is to allocate memory for a new copy of a string.

If you really must mess around with C-style strings for some reason, you can compare them with `strcmp`. But C++ strings are much more convenient; use them unless there's a very good reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

Always use `strcmp` to compare `char *`'s.

Answer (score 1):

strdup copies the string and returns a pointer to a new string allocated in memory. This pointer has a different address than the original string, so you can compare the two using strcmp(), but comparing the pointers will fail due to the different memory locations those strings are at.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the equality operator on pointers, unless there is an overload, it will compare *the pointers*. So when you do `s_convert == "fun"` you compare the *pointer* `s_convert` to the pointer to the string literal `"fun"`.

The reason that it works for `c == "fun"` is because `c` already points to that string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
0 == strcmp( c, "fun" );
```

instead of

```
c == "fun";
```